# Find MAX based on first character with given conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max

Looking to achieve the result in column Parent status which is based on the status of the Subsidiary. The parent is assigned the highest status of any given Subsidiary.

| Sub | Sub Status | Parent | Parent Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA11 | 1-Start | AA | 2-Mid |
| VB12 | 1-Start | BB | 3-Complete |
| XB11 | 1-Start | CC | 1-Start |
| AA12 | 2-Mid | AA | 2-Mid |
| AA13 | 1-Start | AA | 2-Mid |
| BB13 | 2-Mid | BB | 3-Complete |
| RW11 | 3-Complete | BB | 3-Complete |
| FX22 | 1-Start | DD | 2-Mid |
| TF11 | 2-Mid | DD | 2-Mid |

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Can you explain how `Parent Status` coming.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.

[image]

If one has Excel O365:

```
=@SORT(FILTER(B$2:B$10;C$2:C$10=C2),,-1)
```

Or a more general solution:

```
=INDEX({"1-Start","2-Mid","3-Complete"},MAX(LEFT(B$2:B$10,1)*(C$2:C$10=C2)))
```

This would auto-CSE in Excel O365, previous versions of Excel can handle:

```
=INDEX({"1-Start","2-Mid","3-Complete"},MAX(INDEX(LEFT(B$2:B$10,1)*(C$2:C$10=C2),)))
```

---

I'd use a lookup-table instead of the nested array of values if you have a much larger list to choose from btw (though this answer is based, as per your requirement, on the leftmost digit only!).

If you want to do this independent on a lookup table, but all you know is `SUB STATUS`, you could use a CSE:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((LEFT(B$2:B$10,FIND("-",B$2:B$10)-1)*1)=MAX((LEFT(B$2:B$10,FIND("-",B$2:B$10)-1))*(C$2:C$10=C2)))*(C$2:C$10=C2),B$2:B$10)
```